# Why use 0d_ in DiffOrig in Vim?

Tags: vim

In the online manual of Vim, `:help DiffOrig`
will show the recommended command sequence to get changes of current editing file.

Here it is:

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
                   \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

I wonder what the effect of `0d_` is. I tried `0d_` in normal mode, it works like `dd`, but I can't understand why it used here.

Comment: Your downfall here is thinking that `0d_` is a normal mode command when it's actually an ex command.  Anything in a pipeline like that will always be an ex command.  What's actually being run here is akin to `:0delete _` if that makes it clear.

Comment: Addition to @RandyMorris comment: if you need to play normal mode keystrokes in ex mode you can use `:norm` (and conjugate with `:exec` to bind it): this is roughly equivalent to `... | exec 'norm gg"_dd' | diffthis | ...`.

Comment: @Randy Morris, Thanks. I was wrong to think that is a normal mode command actually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's explain it a bit: Suppose you have original foo.txt containing (with line numbers):

```
1 a
2 c
3 d
~
```

You have added a line containing “b” between lines 1 and 2:

- `:vert new` creates a new, empty, buffer in a vertical split (`:help :new`)
- `:set bt=nofile` makes it a scratch buffer (`:help 'bt'`). Note:

  ```
  1 a  | 1 ·<cursor here
  2 b  | ~
  3 c  | ~
  4 d  | ~
  ~    | ~
  ```
- `:r #` inserts **after** current line, contents of alternate file (#), as stored on the file system. You haven't saved the other buffer, so you get original content. (`:help alternate-file`).
  `:help :r` tells you that it always inserts after. Therefore:

  ```
  1 a  | 1
  2 b  | 2 a
  3 c  | 3 c
  4 d  | 4 d
  ~    | ~
  ```
- `:0d_` removes the first line. Why `0`, I don't know it really, I would rather
  write it `:1d_`. `:help range` tells:

  > When using a 0 (zero) this is interpreted as a 1 by most commands

  The `_` specifies that it goes to the black-hole register. See
  `:help :d` about the `:d` ex command, it works linewise.

The rest is obvious.

Comment: TL;DR ":0d_ removes the first line" - the rest is obvious :) +1

Comment: @sehe: TL;DR `:0d_` removes the first line because `:r` inserted original file contents below a blank line.

Comment: Thanks you both very much. It delete the first line to the black-hole register.